# Connecting to a remote mysql server using a function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using wordpress and I have a remote mysql server for some other data not stored on wordpress db.

Now I want to connect to that remote mysql server in a form of a php function but i don't know how or if it is possible. Basically this function serves as to check if `$orderid` exist on the remote mysql server.

```
function check_orderid($orderid) {
// Connect to database
// Check if $orderid exist if yes return true.
}
```

The remote server does accept remote connections.

Also, Is it okay and will not affect wordpress db connection?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Just make one normal php/mysql connection.
And run your query..

Comment: @Salketer `Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.`

Comment: I have updated my post. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to a remote server is not different from connecting to a local server, besides the host address. Just replace the 'localhost' with a resolvable dns name, or the ip address from your remote server, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

To make multiple connection you have to use links.

they are created after successful connect:

```
$link1 = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$link2 = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user2', 'my_password2', 'my_db2');
```

you can use them like:

```
mysqli_query($link1, "your first query as string");
mysqli_query($link2, "your second query as string");
```

By official OO version you should use:

```
$mysqli1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$mysqli2 = new mysqli('externalIP', 'my_user2', 'my_password2', 'my_db2');
$mysqli1->query("some query");
$mysqli1->query("some other query");
```

so, in this case you can easily do this:

```
 $externaldbcon = new mysqli('ExtrnalDBIP', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
 $externaldbcon->query("your query for external DB");
```